# How to tag questions about the new Angular2 version (4.0.0)

Tags: discussion, tags

**Excuse:**
This question isn't about strict coding, but it's about issues and problems concerning the new version of Angular2.

**Introduction:** 
As we know, yesterday, a new stable version of Angular2 (4.0.0) was released. 
(If you don't believe me, see it here: [release history](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md)) It's not a big deal, because Angular 4.0.0 did not make such big changes like Angular2 in relation to AngularJS. In fact, Angular 4.0.0 is a continuation of Angular2. You can read more about it [here](http://angularjs.blogspot.com/2016/12/ok-let-me-explain-its-going-to-be.html) and [here](http://www.infoworld.com/article/3150716/application-development/forget-angular-3-google-skips-straight-to-angular-4.html).

**So...**
Everyone should know that a new tag [angular4](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/angular4/info) has been created on Stack Overflow. You can report issues or ask questions about problems with migrating your project to the new version in this tag. When you have already migrated your project and resolved all your problems, you ask yourself a question: How should I tag a new problem (not necessarily related to migration)? Still `angular2`, now `angular4` or maybe we should create new summary tag. It will be a problem, when AngularJS is completely different than Angular2 and Angular4.

You have to admit that naming and versioning of Angular is embarrassing.

**Question:** What ideas do you have for solving this problem? Are there any already? How are you going to tag new questions about Angular2 and Angular4 projects?

Comment: Is there going to be a new tag for angular5, angular6, angular7 and so on? This sounds like it can get confusing pretty quickly.